# Saving an image after tf.image.resize

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to resize some images using tensorflows image resizing method. I have a loop where I load in the image, resize and then try to write it back out using cv2.imwrite(). However, it continues to error out, does this not output an image? Here's my code:

```
j=0
for i in images:
  skyr_img = imread(my_data_dir+'/'+str(i)) #converts image to  an array
  skyr_img=tf.image.resize(skyr_img,[171,256],antialias=True,method='bilinear')
  print(skyr_img.shape,j)
  cv2.imwrite(my_data_dir+'/train/img'+str(j),skyr_img)
  j=j+1
```

and this is the error I get:

```
(171, 256, 4) 0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-80ea3aae6498> in <module>
      4   skyr_img=tf.image.resize(skyr_img,[171,256],antialias=True,method='bilinear')
      5   print(skyr_img.shape,j)
----> 6   cv2.imwrite(my_data_dir+'/train/img'+str(j),skyr_img)
      7   j=j+1

error: OpenCV(4.6.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'imwrite'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - img is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'img'
```

Comment: `tf.resize()` returns a tensor. Try converting to an ndarray with the `.numpy()` method.

Comment: Ye, just run `cv2.imwrite(my_data_dir+'/train/img'+str(j),skyr_img.numpy())`

Comment: That gives me a different error

```error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-e9c38d709e28> in <module>
      4   skyr_img=tf.image.resize(skyr_img,[171,256],antialias=True,method='bilinear')
      5   print(skyr_img.shape,j)
----> 6   cv2.imwrite(my_data_dir+'/train/img'+str(j),skyr_img.numpy())
      7   j=j+1

error: OpenCV(4.6.0) /io/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp:730: error: (-2:Unspecified error) could not find a writer for the specified extension in function 'imwrite_'```

Comment: Try: `cv2.imwrite(my_data_dir+'/train/img'+str(j) + '.png',skyr_img.numpy())` or  `cv2.imwrite(my_data_dir+'/train/img'+str(j) + '.jpg',skyr_img.numpy())`

Comment: OK i got a different error this time:
```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-ff4df430cfcc> in <module>
      4   skyr_img=tf.image.resize(skyr_img,[171,256],antialias=True,method='bilinear')
      5   skyr_img = skyr_img.numpy()
----> 6   cv2.imwrite(my_data_dir+'/train/img'+str(j)+'.png',skyr_img.numpy())
      7   j=j+1

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'numpy'```

Comment: then remove the `numpy()` part.

Comment: Well it executed, so that part is great! However, it only saves empty images. If I do plt.imshow(skyr_img) the image shows to screen, but, cv2.imwrite doesn't save it. Is there a better way to save images to drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using colab you can mount your drive to colab using

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive', force_remount=True)
```

You can save images to your drive using

```
img = cv2.imread('/content/gold.jpeg')
resized_img = tf.image.resize(img, (1050, 1610)).numpy()
path ='/content/drive/MyDrive'
cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path , 'fish.jpg'), resized_img)
```

Please refer to this working [gist](https://gist.github.com/kiransair/d21d5ed92ddae404cba1805de579ba5a). Thank You.